# What's the proper event to use for onFocus button after 2nd form is closed?

Tags: c#

Using: C# Forms VS2015

What I'm trying to do:

1. On form1, I have a **textbox** (tbJobTitle) and a **button** (bChooseJobTitle -> form2) for a "Job Title" of an employee.
2. The **textbox**(enabled=false) displays the chosen Job Title of an employee.
3. The **button** bChooseJobTitle opens another form (form2) that has a **datagrid** and **2 buttons** (Choose & Cancel)

   ```
   using System.Threading;
   ...
   Thread the1;
   ...
   private void bChooseJobTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       the1 = new Thread(OpenNew_tblJobTitle);
       the1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       the1.Start();
   }
   private void OpenNew_tblJobTitle(object obj)
   {
       Application.Run(new form2());
   }
   ...
   ```
4. I initially set a global string MyVar.Employee_Choose_idJobTitle (default "" ) to store the choosen index primary key if the user selected content and click the Choose button. If the Cancel button is click the MyVar.Employee_Choose_idJobTitle will remain = "".

   ```
   //... at form2 "Choose" button
   private void bChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MyVar.idJobTitle = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       this.Close();
   }

   private void bCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.Close();
   }
   ```
5. When form2 is closed either by "Choose" button or "Cancel" button, the focus goes back to form1's bChooseJobTitle **button**.

**How do I trigger this event?**

...so that can test if the content of MyVar.idJobTitle is not null and add the proper value to my textbox.

I was looking for the **button events** like onFocus or activate but could not find any. Do I use form events instead to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, use event Form Activate if you like.

```
    private void form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyVar.idJobTitle != "")
        { 
            tbJobTitle.Text = Choose_idJobTitle; 
            MyVar.idJobTitle = "";
        }
    }
```